# How to add classes to Symfony 4 "ChoiceType" item labels?

Tags: html, css, symfony, class, label

I have here four radio buttons, and I want to add a css class to each label of the radio button. How can I do that? I have tried two ways but neither are working:

Try 1:

```html
        ->add('background', ChoiceType::class, ['label'=>'2. Dein Hintergrund: ', 
        //this adds class to the parent div
        'attr' => ['class' => 'label'],
        'choices'  => [
            1 => 1,
            2 => 2,
            3 => 3,
            4 => 4
        ], 'choice_value' => null,
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        // this adds class to all radios/input elements
        'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value){
            return ['class' => 'radio radio_'.($key)];
         },
         //this does NOT work, no error but it will not render a class to the label! Why?
         'label_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value){
            return ['class' => 'label'.($key)];
         },
        ])
```

Try 2:

```html
 <div class="container">
   {{ form_label(form.background, {'attr': {'class': 'label'}}) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.background) }}
            <button class="button_main">Übernehmen</button>
        </div>
```

With number 2 I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

I have looked at this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) many times but can't figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your own implementation of the template:

```
<div class="col-12">
    {{ form_label(form.expandedField) }}
    {% for child in form.expandedField.children %}
        <div class="group-15">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-checkbox-primary">
                {{ form_widget(child, {'attr': {'class': 'custom-control-input'}}) }}   
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ child.vars.id }}" >{{ child.vars.label }}</label>   
            </div>  
        </div>  
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Is not possible to add your own class to labels in FormTypes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own form template like in [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: My Try 2 is from that documentation, but I get this error which I cannot seem to get rid of!

Comment: please try this 
 `<div class="container">
 {{ form_label(form.background, 'label value', {
       'label_attr': {'class': 'label'}
}) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.background) }}
            <button class="button_main">Übernehmen</button>
        </div>`
  
  i have change 'attr' by 'label_attr'

Comment: Fair approach, but not what I need! It creates a new label element above the container and adds the class 'foo' to it!

Comment: If you don't wont symfony label, don't use form_label, just add your class to the widget like this
`<div class="container">
   {{ form_widget(form.background, {'attr': {'class': 'task_field'}}) }}
            <button class="button_main">Übernehmen</button>
        </div>`

Comment: this adds a class to the container element of the form, i am trying to get the class on the label element!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't modify the attributes of a choice label of ChoiceType. This feature does not exist in Symfony core for the moment. Please have a look to [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18318).